# Hive query is scanning all partitions when using unix_timestamp('2015-07-06','yyyy-MM-dd')*1000 function , how to fix this issue?

Tags: sql, hive

I have partitioned my table on dt which is epoch timestamp  e.g 1435689000000
,1435689000000
,1435775400000
when I am query my table by using

```
SELECT 
  report_time,
  msisdn AS msisdn,
  city AS city,
  device_type AS device_type,
  dt AS dt,
  avg(cei_index) as cei_score_reference,  
  avg(data_cei_index) as data_kqi_reference,  
FROM index_1_day
Where dt = unix_timestamp('2015-07-07','yyyy-MM-dd')*1000  
   group by 
  report_time,
  msisdn, 
  city,
  dt,
  device_type;
```

query is scanning all partitions available in table .

I have checked by using EXPLAIN DEPENDENCY.

need help on this issue and I can only use unix_timestamp('2015-07-07','yyyy-MM-dd')*1000  function .